# C++ : struggle with generic const pointer

Tags: c++, templates, stl, constants

I've run into some annoying issues with const-correctness in some templated code, that ultimately boils down to the following observation: for some reason, given an STL-ish Container type T, `const typename T::pointer` does not actually seem to yeild a constant pointer type, even if `T::pointer` is equivalent to `T::value_type*`.

The following example illustrates the problem.  Suppose you have a templated function that takes a Container which must meet the STL Random Access Container concept requirements.

```
template <class Container>
void example(Container& c)
{
    const typename Container::pointer p1 = &c[0]; // Error if c is const
    const typename Container::value_type* p2 = &c[0]; 
}
```

Then, if we pass this function a const container...

```
const std::vector<int> vec(10);
example(vec);
```

...we get an invalid conversion from `const int*` to `int*`.  But why is `const typename Container::pointer` not the same as `const int*` in this example?

Note that if I change `const typename Container::pointer` to simply `typename Container::const_pointer` it compiles fine, however, as far as I can tell, the const_pointer typedef is an extension, (I don't see it mentioned in the C++ standard Container Requirements (23.5, Table 65)), and so therefore I don't want to use it.

So how can I obtain a generic, const-correct pointer type from a container T? (I really can't see how to do this without using boost::mpl::if_ along with type_traits to check if the container is constant...but there must be a less verbose way to do this)

Edit: In case it matters, I'm using gcc 4.3.2 to compile this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't work because your `const` does not apply to what you think it applies to. For example, if you have

```
typedef int* IntPtr;
```

then

```
const IntPtr p;
```

does not stand for

```
const int* p;
```

but rather stands for

```
int* const p;
```

Typedef-name is not a macro. Once the "pointerness" of the type is wrapped into a typedef-name, there's no way to use it to create a pointer-to-const type anymore. I.e. there's absolutely no way to use the above `IntPtr` typedef-name to produce an equivalent of

```
const int* p;
```

You have to either use to pointee type explicitly (as you did with `value_type`), or check whether your container defines a different typedef-name, with `const` already wrapped "inside" (like `const_pointer` or something like that).

Comment: This can be difficult to remember.  The best hint I've come across is to read R to L.  "int* const p" is "const pointer to int", i.e. pointer is const but int is mutable.  "const int *p" is "pointer to int that is const", i.e. pointer is mutable but int is const.

Comment: This answer (and others) is incorrect. All that is needed is using a template to remove the pointer. See my answer for details.

Comment: @darune: Firstly, there's nothing "incorrect" in this answer. Secondly, this answer was written in 2009, when there was no such thing as `std::remove_pointer` at all. And thirdly, no, you don't need to use `std::remove_pointer` when/if you have direct access to the pointee type.

Comment: @AnT The incorrect part im looking at is "there's absolutely no way to use the above IntPtr typedef-name to produce an equivalent of". `std::remove_ptr` is simple to implement using 2009 c++ and has been in boost for a long time. Btw. this is not a blame game, but a service for other users.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
typename Container::pointer
```

Has the type `int*` (in our case). I don't know the terminology, so sorry for that, but pointers point to a type. That is, `Container::pointer` is a pointer to a mutable T, and adding const is only going to make this a const pointer (not a pointer to const), because Container::pointer has already been defined to point to a mutable T.

It seems only `const_pointer`, either from the class or your own:

```
typedef const typename Container::value_type* const_pointer
```

Will work.

Answer (score 2):

The allocator requirements (cf. 20.1.5, Table 32, "Allocator requirements") state that allocators for the STL containers shall have an `Allocator::const_pointer`.  All of the STL containers (the eight containers listed in Section 23) define a `Container::const_pointer` typedef as:

```
typedef typename Allocator::const_pointer const_pointer;
```

As you state in your question, however, containers (other than those eight) are not required to have a `Container::const_pointer` typedef.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on this? I see what you're saying regarding const_pointer as part of the Allocator requirement (in 20.1.5), but where does it say that *Containers* must necessarily define a const_pointer typedef? The closest I see is 20.1.5.4, where it says Container implementations can assume that an Allocator has a const_pointer typedef, not necessarily that the container itself should define a public const_pointer typedef.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the STL requires containers to define a `const_pointer` typedef, just that all of the STL containers do define a `const_pointer` typedef. Sorry for the confusion; I updated my answer to try and make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of relevance here (from [SGI STL reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html#6)):

> [6] As in the case of references [5], the pointer type must have the same semantics as C++ pointers but need not actually be a C++ pointer. "Smart pointers," however, unlike "smart references", are possible. This is because it is possible for user-defined types to define the dereference operator and the pointer member access operator, operator* and operator->.

Comment: In this case however, `T::pointer` is the same as `T::value_type*`, (i.e. `T::pointer` is an actual raw pointer) and so the requirement is fulfilled. – Charles Salvia

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using a template. The trick is to remove the pointer first, then apply const on the type and finally applying pointer to the type - for instance using `std::remove_pointer` yields:

```
typedef const std::remove_pointer<Container::pointer>::type* PointerToConst;
```