# C++: setting constness of pointer based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++11

I have a struct that manages 'views' into an array of variable type. The purpose of this is to provide a unified state vector for ODE simulation while at the same time working on individual segments of this vector from several other classes in an organized fashion. If this triggers a design pattern in your mind, please let me know.

My issue is that the first implementation `ContainerHolderFirst`, using `Cont::pointer` does not compile for const arrays. 
My next attempt with `std::conditional`, mixing in `Cont::const_pointer` still doesn't work. 
Only the third attempt with `std::conditional` and modification of `Cont::value_type` compiles (and seems to work in my larger project).
My questions are the following:

- It would be nice if `ContainerHolderFirst` would work. I'd wish that const-ness of the type would be propagated to the pointer. Why isn't it?
- <del>I understand even less why `ContainerHolderSecond` doesn't work. The explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647394/1707931 rather suggests that this is the way to go, no?</del> It does actually work. My bad.
- Are there issues with the third approach that I haven't uncovered yet? Is there a simpler way?

Full C++11 code follows:

**Update1**: Fixing `ContainerHolderSecond`. It does compile with correct initialization. Also added ContainerHolderBarry suggested by Barry using `decltype` and `declval`.
This leaves the question whether any of the approaches are preferred? Will they lead to performance differences? They should all compile to the same object, no?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename Cont>
class ContainerHolderFirst {
    Cont& data_;

    const static size_t offset_ = 1;
    typename Cont::pointer data_view;
 public:
    ContainerHolderFirst(Cont& data) : data_(data), data_view(&data[offset_]) {}
};

template <typename Cont>
class ContainerHolderSecond {
    using Pointer = typename std::conditional<std::is_const<Cont>::value,
          typename Cont::const_pointer,
          typename Cont::pointer>::type;
    Cont& data_;

    const static size_t offset_ = 1;
    Pointer data_view;

 public:
    ContainerHolderSecond(Cont& data) : data_(data), data_view(&data[offset_]) {}
};

template <typename Cont>
class ContainerHolderBarry {
    using Pointer = decltype(&std::declval<Cont&>()[0]);
    Cont& data_;

    const static size_t offset_ = 1;
    Pointer data_view;

 public:
    ContainerHolderBarry(Cont& data) : data_(data), data_view(&data[offset_]) {}
};


int main() {
    using namespace std;
    array<int, 2> my_array;
    ContainerHolderFirst<array<int, 2>> holder(my_array); // works

    const array<int, 2> const_array{5,7};
    // ContainerHolderFirst<const array<int, 2>> const_holder(const_array);
    /* error: invalid conversion from 'const value_type* {aka const int*}' to 'std::array<int, 2ull>::pointer {aka int*}' [-fpermissive] */

    ContainerHolderSecond<array<int,2>> second_holder(my_array); // works!
    ContainerHolderSecond<const array<int,2>> const_holder(const_array); //updated; works as well; awkward

    ContainerHolderThird<array<int,2>> third_holder(my_array); // still works
    ContainerHolderThird<const array<int,2>> third_const_holder(const_array); //finally compiles as well

    ContainerHolderBarry<array<int,2>> barry_holder(my_array);
    ContainerHolderBarry<const array<int,2>> barry_const_holder(const_array);
}
```

Comment: Why do your views into a container hold a reference to the container?  Your containers are contiguous buffers: why are the views into a contiguous buffer a function of the type of the buffer in question?  The only state they need is either a pointer and length, or two pointers?

Comment: The reference to the container isn't strictly necessary and I don't think I'm using it actually. In the beginning, I wanted to store the data inside such a ContainerHolder, but I anticipated quite some copying overhead or me studying up on move-semantics. Now, the reference kinda stayed. I'm essentially storing pointer and length (omitted in the code here). Are you essentially suggesting to do this as ```template <typename value_type>``` and then ```ContainerHolder<array::value_type>```?

Comment: `std::experimental::array_view` or write your own.

Comment: I have looked at array_view (or now span) from the GSL packages. I ran into a bug there that stops me for now and they're not supporting C++11 anyway. I also cannot find much about ```std::experimental::array_view``` on Google and if I'm not mistaken this has been abandoned, although I only heard that in a video presentation. I need multiple views into one array, so I've decided rolling my own. Could you confirm that you would rather template over value_type instead of Cont here?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4512.html http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3851.pdf -- why do you think it was abandoned?  Those are pretty full specs.  But sure, if you roll your own array_view, it will template on the elements being viewed, and the `const` ness of the thing being viewed would be *in that type*.  (array views themselves are analogous to pointers; a const pointer and a pointer to const are different things.  Do not presume a `const` array view cannot modify its elements: rather it cannot *change* its begin/end point.)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Z3c4Sv52U (presentation from cppcon) Consider what is being said after 58:55 or so. It's very short and I cannot really judge how legitimate it is although the person seems credible to me. But yeah, I'm very, very far from this process, so chances are I misunderstood this.

Regarding the rest of your suggestions. It may be obvious to you, but could you spell out that ```auto view = View<T>(array)``` is the usage you propose? I hear your warning regarding ```const``` of the type and the view.
I hear your warning regarding const view<T>(array).

Comment: My personal array view has an implicit ctor from vector&, array&, T(&)[N], and basic_string&, plus (for an array view to const) to `vector<non_const_T>const&` etc.  Plus pointer-length and two-pointer ctors.  Toss on typical range operations (begin, end, front, back, empty, size, `[]`) and some manipulators (array_view without_front(C=1)const, array_view without_back(C=1)const), and bob is your uncle.  Mine only supports 1-dimensional arrays for now, and does not support stride.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You're making this unnecessarily difficult on yourself. If you want the type of `&cont[offset]`, just ask for the type of *that expression*. Use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) along with `decltype`:

```
template <typename Cont>
class ContainerHolder {
    using Pointer = decltype(&std::declval<Cont&>()[0]);
    ...
};
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what's going on here? I'm using declval with a reference to Cont, then I'm accessing [0] of some array and looking at the address of that?

Comment: @MatthiasKauer `declval<T>` just gives you a `T&&`. You can conceptually think of it as just `T()`, but it works for non-default-constructible types. So this is effectively `decltype(&cont[0])`, which is the type that you care about.

Comment: Using unary `operator&` in generic code is never a good idea.  Too many people get "clever" and make `&` return a pointer to a different type.  (Really; as an example, com smart pointers often do this because a lot of com interfaces expect to be given a pointer-to-a-pointer to populate)

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with `ContainerHolderSecond` is that you're using it incorrectly:

```
ContainerHolderSecond<array<int,2>> const_holder(const_array);
//                    ^-- insert "const" here
```

As for `ContainerHolderFirst`, the reason that `array<T, N>::pointer` is the same type as `(array<T, N> const)::pointer` is that there is no automatic way to determine where the `const` qualification should be added to the nested type, and there is no language facility to describe this (that is, we don't have `const`-qualified typedefs or type aliases).

Comment: awkward. I came with the expectation that it wouldn't work because I couldn't get it to work in the larger code base, but you're correct. I'll update in a moment.